# Callback gets fired with an alert function is present and it not fire without an alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the alert function is present (shown below), the callback function gets fired and everything works. When the alert function is not present, the callback function never gets fired.

```
  function getTableData(tableName, startRow, endRow, callback)
  {
    CK.getData = $.getJSON("getTableData.php",{tN: tableName, sR: startRow, eR: endRow}, function(dataTable){});

    alert("test"); 
    CK.getData.done(function()
    {
       // load data inside table using an $.each function...
       callback(); // works only when the alert function above is present..
    });
  }

   getTableData(tableName, startRow, endRow, function()
   {
      $(".logTable").after($addRowData); 
   });
```

Comment: This is because `$.getJSON` is **async**. When you add the `alert`, you give the async call time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the ajax function is non-blocking (asynchronous), meaning the each loop continues on without waiting for a response. By the time you get a response from any of the getJSON call you've finished iteration.

I wrap the ajax function within a closure:

```
  (function(tableName, startRow, endRow)
  { 
      getTableData(tableName, startRow, endRow, function()
      {
        $(".logTable").after($addRowData); 
      });

  })(tableName, startRow, endRow);
```

And set the async variable within $.ajax object to false for sync. communication.